# Pervent rapid update of a column

Tags: mysql, triggers

So lets say I have a column on my users table called `current_status`
and I want at least 5 second gaps between updates on that column

In another word if one part of the code should update this column no other code should be able to change it for 5 second after that .

**i know 100 ways to do tat on the code but i want to do it on database level mainly becuz its a big website and the original programer is not available !**

i'm thinking about some sort of trigger or something that works with time ? 
here it is , now how can i apply 5 sec rule to it ?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `status_update` BEFORE update ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW IF OLD.current_status != NEW.current_status  THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot update record for 5 sec ';
END IF
//
DELIMITER ;
```

---

i have table called `status_changes` for tracking these changes , i add a row to this table every time status changes

status_changes : `id` , `user_id` , `timestamp` , `current_status`

Comment: i'm sure i saw this question yesterday. anyway. create another table, that has a single field, which is defined as thus `last_update datetime`.  initialise this to some time in the past.  

Then in your trigger, check the value of that field. If it was more than 5 seconds ago, allow the update, and update the value of that field to `NOW()`.

Comment: how can i check if its been more than 5 sec in trigger ?

Comment: You store the last time something was inserted and check against that

Comment: @pala_ thanx , i know that i was asking for syntax apparently it's something like `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(), column ))<5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution, but if you know what you are doing you could use something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `status_update`
BEFORE update ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
  IF (OLD.current_status != NEW.current_status
      AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(), OLD.ts))<5) THEN
      BEGIN
        SET NEW.current_status=OLD.current_status;
        SET NEW.ts=OLD.ts;
      END;
END IF;
```

(or you can block the update with an error using SIGNAL like in your example).

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cc49/1).

Comment: @max ts is the current timestamp, you need to store it somehow but you should have it already ... have a look at this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html this trigger will allow changes to be made to other fields but not to `current_status` or to `ts`

Comment: thanx , yeah i got it right after posting my question and looking at fiddle code , i did delete it but  apparently you saw it anyway ! thanx again